# Does the set of all glide reflections and translations form a subgroup of the group of motions of the plane?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

I'm confused by the question. I believe that the set is closed, since the composition of a glide reflection with a translation is itself a glide reflection.

I think there's no identity element, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: The identity element is of course a translation of distance $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this you are supposed to verify the group axioms.  To show that the set is closed you need to keep going.  The composition of two translations is a translation.  What about the composition of two glide reflections and the composition of a glide reflection and a translation?

There is an identity-the translation by $0$.  Are there inverses?  Finally you have to prove the operation is associative.

Comment: Of course. And since the composition of two glide reflections is not a glide reflection, it's not closed. As far as the identity being 0, what about when you're composing a glide reflection with a translation? It doesn't translate, but wouldn't it still reflect? Or does the identity element apply to the reflection as well?

Comment: @HamSandwich: Something in your argument doesn't add up. You have to consider glide reflections *and* translations. That the composition of 2 glide reflections is not a glide reflections isn't enough. You also have to show that it isn't a translation (at least, not always). Once you've done that, you know that the operation is not closed.

Comment: An inversion is a glide reflection with no translation component.  It is part of our set.  The identity being a $0$ translation means that you can compose either a translation or glide reflection with a $0$ translation and get the same translation or glide reflection.  The composition of two glide reflections is a translation, so it is in our set.

Comment: Sorry, a minute ago I made a comment but when I reread I answered my own question.

Comment: @rschwieb:  that is the definition of glide reflection I am used to, but it is acceptable for the translation to be $0$.  If you don't allow the zero translation you don't have inverses or closure under addition of translations.